# Slow POST to ASP.NET MVC site from Webforms site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, webforms

We have a WebForms+MVC 1.0 application where the WebForms site posts an encrypted string to an action in the MVC site which then displays a details view. However in our (clustered) test environment, the post from Webforms can take close to a minute before displaying the MVC view. The MVC action makes a WCF service call to get customer data from an Oracle database. This "slow post" effect only occurs when a user access the application for the first time - the second time around the response times are fast. Any ideas what could be causing this initial slow response time? Does it have to do something with the MVC routing? We don't experience this in our dev server environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the MVC application is up and running when the first request comes in?  The delay might simply be its load time.

Comment: Yes, the MVC app is up and running. 

User1 may have already accessed and done the POST, but if user2 accesses it for the first time and does the POST to the MVC site, user2 will initially experience this slow response time.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any heavy weight operations that take place when you establish a new session?

Comment: Upon posting to the MVC action, a WCF service instance is created, a couple of business objects are instantiated and some custom validation takes place. Thats about it.